# Magento 2 Data Migration SQL error 'Column not found'

Tags: magento2, database, fatal-error, magento2-migration-tool

I'm trying to use the Magento 2 migration tool to move a 1.6 site over to 2.1.4. When i get to the `[stage: data migration][step: PostProcessing Step]: started` step, i get this error:

> [Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]                                                                                SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ccp.entity_id' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `ccp`.`entity_id` FROM `catalog_category_product` AS `ccp` WHERE (ccp.category_id = 1)

Looking over the M1 DB, there is no `entity_id` in the `catalog_category_product` table, so something is getting screwy (the technical term) when the migration wrap up is happening.

I have tried adding this to my `map.xml` file:

```
<ignore><field>catalog_category_product.entity_id</field></ignore>
```

But this error is happening much later in the process so i don't think it's a mapping issue.

This might not me related, but when i refresh the front end, i get this error:

> a:4:{i:0;s:60:"Unable to load theme by specified key: 'default/{name of the old 1.6 install's theme}'";i:1;s:9773:"#0 /home/demo/public_html/oberk/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/View/Design.php(148): Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\FlyweightFactory->create('default/{name of the old 1.6 install's theme}', 'frontend')

I haven't been able to track down where i need to look for a solution to the issue, since i'm not much of a sql guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's precisely your issue: there's supposed to be a `entity_id` field in the `catalog_category_product` table. Here's the code that creates it:

```
//From \Magento\Catalog\Setup\InstallSchema, lines 1202-1210

$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('catalog_category_product'))
    ->addColumn(
        'entity_id',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        null,
        ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
        'Entity ID'
    )
```

The issue you need to figure out is why the `entity_id` column has been deleted.

Comment: Man, what a obvious point!!! You are right that there is a `entity_id` in the M2 site, but i'm looking at a bunch of M1 sites, and none of them have that column in that same table `(catalog_category_product)`. So i'm thinking that i have something off in my mapping. Just for fun i did try adding the column into the M1 site that i'm trying to move over, but not such luck, i still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**tjons** is correct in his answer, but i wanted to add some more context to the specifics of my problem and what fixed it.

It turns out that in a M1 site, there is no `entity_id` in the `catalog_category_product` table, but there is one in the default M2 site. Somehow in the creation of my M2 site that i was moving my M1 site to, that column wasn't created and therefore there was nothing to map to.

If you look in the `map.xml.dist` file that is used for default mapping or the `map.xml` that is used for custom mapping, you will see this:

```
<destination>
   <field_rules>
      ...
      <ignore>
         <field>catalog_category_product.entity_id</field>
      </ignore>
      ...
    </field_rules>
</destination>
```

Which should correctly ignore the `entity_id` column on the M2 site. But what the migration tool doesn't do is create the column if it's not there in the first place.

Taking a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829400/troubles-of-adding-a-new-id-auto-increment-after-table-exist) I found a few different ways to add this column into my M2 site. This is not advised, as it's hacking the DB directly, and for the most part isn't tested fully by me. But as i am working on a dev site that i can ruin to my hearts content, it's safe to play around with. The SQL query i ran on the M2 DB is:

```
ALTER TABLE `catalog_category_product` DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_category_product` ADD `entity_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

This created the column and incremented it down every row. I ran the migration tool and bam! it completed without issue.

For anyone finding this, **DO NOT DO THIS ON A PRODUCTION SITE EVER!** This is for dev site work only and serves as a way to get a better understanding of the error.